# When to use a dot in elixir module name?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I have seen elixir modules named this way:

```
defmodule Foo.bar.baz do
end
```

But I can't find any documentation stating when to do this.

Does it have to do with subdirectories? Using mix, I can put my modules in subdirectories within the lib folder, and they work fine without dots.

For example:

```
# this is in /lib/foo/bar

defmodule Bar do
end
```

What is the convention?

Comment: AFAIK the convention is to use them when it makes sense to organize your modules this way--noting that modules aren't *really* hierarchical--they're just atoms, e.g., you can have `Foo.Bar.Baz` defined without having a `Foo` or `Foo.Bar`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing special about `.`. You can give a module any name you want as long as it's a valid atom, including e.g. whitespace:

```
iex(1)> defmodule :"hello world!!!" do
...(1)>   def hi, do: :ok
...(1)> end
iex(2)> :"hello world!!!".hi
:ok
```

You're also not required to name the modules the same as the file/folder they're in. You can define any module in any `.ex` file inside `lib` and they'll be available to the whole application and `iex`.

The convention, if a file declares a single module at the top level, is to name it based on its path, excluding `lib`, converting each path segment to capital case. For example, `lib/foo/bar/baz.ex` usually defines a module named `Foo.Bar.Baz`.

Answer (score 4):

The convention is only to name all your modules inside your application/package as `MyApp.MyModule` (assuming that your application/package is named `MyApp`.) That is more or less similar to java convention to name packages `com.example.blah...`.

This is done to prevent name clashes between different applications/packages.

Elixir core modules are not namespaced (there are some exceptions like `String.Chars`, though.)

Inside your application/package it is totally up to you whether to choose the flat model for module naming, or hierarchical.

BTW, the module name might be any valid atom. The dot is the convention only, it affects neither mode accessibility for the compiler nor anything else. [`Module.concat/{1,2}`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html#concat/1) helper uses dot to build up module names, but again this is the convention only.